# How to automatically kill / terminate process as soon as it is launched?

Tags: command-line, bash, process, automation, kill

Is there a way to automatically kill a certain (sub)process the very moment it is launched? I've read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389543/using-a-shell-script-to-automatically-kill-processes) answer how to filter a process by its name and kill it:

`sudo ps aux | grep '<process name>' | awk '{2}' | xargs kill -9`

But instead of e.g. setting up a script that executes above command periodically, I would like the system to watch out for the process in question and terminate it automatically as soon as it pops up.

*Edit*: This shorter command, which targets the process by its name instead of its PID, should do it as well:

`sudo killall -I -s SIGKILL <process name>`

Comment: You could set a cronjob, but wouldn't it be a better path to try to prevent the process from starting in the first place?  What is the process?

Comment: It is not possible to kill a process as soon as it starts. However, since you know the process "name", I conclude that you know the executable file name of the process you are interested. So, it will be better to locate the executable file and rename (move) it or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

A `cron` job won't work as the standard version does not support execution frequencies higher than 1 Hz (every 1 second). Plus, as you already mentioned, saving your credentials into a file is usually a bad idea

Comment: This does not answer the question. Better suited as a comment.